# BlueSky Statistics - Retaining Factors in Datasets on saving

Tags: r

I define some variables as Factors.
I have used both the GUI & Variable sheet approach.
I save the Dataset in *.xlsx format.
When I Open the Dataset at a later stage these definitions are lost.
How can I retain these definitions?
Must the keep the syntax from the GUI and rerun it each time?

Regards
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Save the dataset to a R object. In the Save As type select R Object (*.RData)